# No route to host with nc but can ping

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, firewall, netcat

I'm trying to connect to port 25 with netcat from one virtual machine to another but It's telling me `no route to host` although i can ping. I do have my firewall default policy set to drop but I have an exception to accept traffic for port 25 on that specific subnet. I can connect from VM 3 TO VM 2 on port 25 with nc but not from VM 2 TO 3.

Here's a preview of my firewall rules for VM2

[image: screenshot]

Here's a preview of my firewall rules for VM 3

[image: screenshot]

When I show the listening services I have `*:25` which means it's listening for all ipv4 ip addresses and `:::25` for ipv6 addresses. I don't understand where the error is and why is not working both firewall rules accept traffic on port 25 so it's supposed to be connecting. I tried comparing the differences between both to see why I can connect from vm3 to vm2 but the configuration is all the same. Any suggestions on what could be the problem?

> Update stopping the iptable service resolves the issue but I still
>   need those rules to be present.

Comment: Please, avoid screen shots when possible. Instead, edit your question and copy-paste your terminal text. Thanks.

Comment: Pasting the output as a text would be much better (browser search, copy paste, in the end it's text, why to post it as image)?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Your `no route to host` while the machine is ping-able is the sign of a firewall that denies you access politely (i.e. with an ICMP message rather than just DROP-ping).

See your `REJECT` lines? They match the description (REJECT with ICMP xxx). The problem is that those seemingly (#) catch-all REJECT lines are in the middle of your rules, therefore the following rules won't be executed at all. (#) Difficult to say if those are actual catch-all lines, the output of `iptables -nvL` would be preferable.

Put those REJECT rules at the end and everything should work as expected.

Comment: Didn't think that it could be the case! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[xhienne answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/353458/209677) is absolutely correct, but even the reason might be the firewall, in case the issue happen with port 80/tcp often the reason this happens is due to the presence of a proxy server. Connection should through instead (direct connection if https (443/tcp)). Some programs use `$http_proxy` environment variable. On some other cases you can just:

```
http_proxy="http://nameOrIPOfProxy:proxyPort" command
```

For `apt` you should set something like

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://nameOrIPOfProxy:proxyPort";
Acquire::https::Proxy "false";
```

on `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy.conf`.