# netcat no route to host on port 80 but not on 22

Tags: networking

I am in a vpn into another country. I have a VM there that I can reach via ssh. It's awfully slow but it works. Netcat to port 22 also shows open port and reports with openSSH banner. So the routing to the host works.

However when I try the same IP with another port like port 80, nc fails with "no route to host". How does one port pass through but the other doesn't find a route? I thought Route is IP and not TCP?

Comment: I bet the VPN is connected via an  ISP residential contract.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"No route to host" is the sign that a firewall rule denies access to the specified port with an ICMP message rather than just DROPping.

[source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/353452/no-route-to-host-with-nc-but-can-ping#answer-353458)